# XPages Ext Lib Value Picker onChange event

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using a the extension library value picker to select a Name.  Once the user hits Ok, I need to use the selected value to populate several other fields. But I can't figure out how to fire a SSJS function from the Ok button.

Thanks for any suggestions.

-- Jeff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fire an event from the field that the value picker updates.

Here's a simple example that updates another field when the value picker is used:

```xml
<xe:djextListTextBox id="inputField">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("testField").setValue(getComponent("inputField").getValue())}]]></xe:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:djextListTextBox>

<xe:valuePicker id="valuePicker1" for="inputField">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:simpleValuePicker valueList="1,2,3" valueListSeparator=","></xe:simpleValuePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:valuePicker>

<xp:br />
<xp:inputText id="testField"></xp:inputText>
```

Comment: I'd say that's the best way of doing it. It's the method I've used

Comment: Thanks - I was playing with the value Change listener, but that only fires on validation.